# CSS3 PIE - No Server Side?

Tags: css3pie

I am using a Hosted CMS which does not allow server side access. And unless I am mistaken CSS3 Pie requires server side code to work properly. (`.htaccess`)

Is there a way to use CSS3 Pie (or another similar type of service) without server side access?

Comment: You don't need any serverside code for css3pie. And you can always use the js file (which I would not recommend).

Comment: Where do you want to use the `.htaccess` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways:

- add the mime type using .htaccess
- Use the supplied PHP file to add the mimetype
- Use pie-js: http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/

As mentioned on their page:

> **Advantages of the JS version**
>
> Since it is a normal .js file, PIE.js does not suffer from some of the
>   more annoying limitations of the PIE.htc behavior:
>
> You can load PIE.js from a different domain than the HTML page. You
>   don't have to worry about your server not using the correct
>   Content-type header for the file. Referencing the PIE.js file via a
>   relative path is simpler since you only have to do it once in each
>   HTML page. It is more easily integrated within JavaScript libraries.
>
> **Disadvantages of the JS version**
>
> Unfortunately there are some significant drawbacks to using PIE.js,
>   which is why the .htc behavior is still the recommended approach for
>   most users:
>
> Invoking it requires writing some JavaScript, which means your styling
>   is scattered between CSS and JS code. The .js file blocks the parsing
>   of the page while it is loading, whereas the .htc file loads
>   asynchronously. You have to wait until the page's DOM has completely
>   loaded before applying PIE.js to elements, whereas the .htc behavior
>   applies itself while the page is still loading. This means the "flash
>   of unstyled content" problem is much greater with PIE.js. PIE.js
>   cannot automatically attach and detach itself from elements which are
>   dynamically added to/removed from the page's DOM, so you have to write
>   code to handle that yourself.

Comment: I completely missed that when reading the CSS3 Pie page. Thanks